# Patsy installation in enthought

Tags: python, enthought

I want patsy module to be installed. I downloaded it from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/patsy.

When I try to run the setup.py I get this error.

```
Warning (from warnings module):
`File "C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.3.0.1715.win-x86\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 267
warnings.warn(msg)
UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires' `
```

Please provide me the detailed step to install patsy. I use enthought canopy (Version: 1.3.0.1715 ) for win 32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this link helped me when I faced this problem.. I folled these steps and installed the patsy.

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Python-Packages-on-Windows-7